# Infinite ajax scroller not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using a plugin called [Infinite Ajax Scroller](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin). The issue I'm having is getting the javascript to work in the new content that has been loaded. I see a few others posted this question, but I can't seem to find an answer. From what I understand reading a similar question you must refire the js in the callback `onRenderComplete`. This doesn't seem to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery.ias({
    container:".posts_container",
    item:".row.home.post",
    pagination:".pagination",
    next:"a[rel*=next]",
    loader:"images/loader.gif",
    onRenderComplete: function() {
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
})
```

Comment: You can't use (modified) original code? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Foatn